:net Maui call wdsl soap generate error only in IOS: An error occurred while deserializing the response message body for the operation
I have the following problem, I have a Visual Studio 17.9.6 .Net MAUI net 8.0, I have a .asmx web service that when connected by soap 1.2 in EndpointConfiguration  I get the following error:
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while deserializing the response message body for the operation

{System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: Si è verificato un errore durante la deserializzazione del corpo del messaggio di risposta per l'operazione 'CheckVersionApp'.
---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 325).
---> System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected end of file. Following elements are not closed: CheckVersionAppResult, CheckVersionAppResponse, Body, Envelope. Line 1, position 325.

please [edit] your question to include additional information

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It is the same issue in this post https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/80935 but in net maui - .net 8.0 platform IOS,in Android work fine: I don't find any solution.
I try with .net 7.0 and it work fine also in IOS, but I need to upgrade framework to .net 8.0 to deploy App at 17.4 version
